# php pdo get only one value from mysql; value that equals to variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have defined variable $row_id1 (for example $row_id1 = 1;)

In mysql is column called Number.

Want to select the column Number and if in the column exists $row_id, want to get (fetch, define) the value. Actually want to check if in column Number exists $row_id value.

What is wrong with the code?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Number FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = :Number1");
$stmt->bindParam(':Number1', $row_id1); //value from $_POST
$stmt->execute();
$Number1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // seems here something is wrong

echo $Number1 .' $Number1<br>';
```

In output I get Array $Number1

As if simple (stupid) question but searching for some hours and no solution

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Updated code**

This part is not related to problem (only for information)

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/_additionally_protected/session.class.php"); 
$session = new session();
// Set to true if using https
$session->start_session('_a', false);

session_regenerate_id();

//require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_additionally_protected/request_blocker.php');  //slow page load

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_measure_time_start.php');

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_additionally_protected/db_config.php');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/only_private/blackhole.php");

ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);
```

This is related to problem (here I get values from input)

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
$row_id1 = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['row_id1']));
else
$row_id1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['row_id1']);
echo $row_id1 .' row_id1 from $_POST<br>';
```

Connect to mysql

```
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass//, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
//echo "Connected to database"; // check for connection
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
//echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
//print "Error!: " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br/>";
//some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
exit;
}
```

Here I get last row number from mysql. Latter I pass the number+1 to html hidden iput field. I mean on page load I get last number. If user clicks on button do not execute the code.

```
//fetch last Number to pass to row_id and entry_id
if( !$_POST['register'] ) {
echo '!$_POST[register] <br>';
//+++++++++++++ now multiple PDO

// Select table with query
$stmt = $db->query("
SELECT Number FROM 2_1_journal ORDER BY Number DESC LIMIT 1
");
// Set fetching mode
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Assign $row as your key to access Table fields
foreach ($stmt as $row) :
echo $row['Number'] .' $row[Number] On page load (reload) get number of last row in   mysql; to pass to Entry ID and rowid<br>';
$_SESSION['last_number_from_mysql'] = $row['Number'];
endforeach;
}//if( !$_POST['register'] ) {
```

**Session (above)**

**This is the part that makes problem for me**
// Get Number from the DB latter to compare with row ID (hidden). Aim to decide if need to record new row or if to update existing. The code is executed on $_POST. So must define $row_id (defined above)

```
if( $_POST['register'] ) {
```

If user click on button only then execute the code

```
echo $row_id1 .' row_id1 before select Number where Number is $row_id1<br>';
```

This is to check. I see row_id1 number; That means that the number is received. And just below want to use it

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Number FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = :Number1"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':Number1', $row_id1);
$stmt->execute();
echo $Number1 = $stmt->fetchColumn() .' $Number1<br>';
```

This echo only if 2 times click on button

Here is html input

```
<input type="tex" name="row_id1" id="row_id1" value="
<?php
//if( ($_POST['register']) === 'Save draft' ) {
//echo $_POST['row_id1'];
//}
//else {
echo ($_SESSION['last_number_from_mysql'] + 1);
//}
?>
">
```

Comment: it looks like session in response for this behavior.

Comment: Yes, session affects the behavior. But session is necessary... will think what to do... may be will place code above sessions...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use the fetch function according to your desired result.

1. If you need a single scalar value, no column name is ever needed:

   ```
    $Number1 = $stmt->fetchColumn();
   ```
2. If there are many results to be returned, but only one column per row, no need for the column name again:

   ```
    $numbers = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
   ```

   It will return an array of numbers.
3. If you need a single row with multiple values, then use `fetch()`
4. If you need array of rows, use `fetchAll()`

Comment: Sorry, if code is like this $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Number FROM 2_1_journal WHERE Number = :Number1");
$stmt->bindParam(':Number1', $row_id1);
$stmt->execute();
echo $Number1 = $stmt->fetchColumn(); then does not work

Comment: Yes, now appears to work. Some mess in my code. Need to check. Thank you.

Comment: Strange behavior. I click on button. With $_POST get variable $row_id (with echo I see $row_id value). Then the code above. But no value ($Number1 = $stmt->fetchColumn()) displayed. When I click input button the second time, $Number1 = $stmt->fetchColumn() echo...Where may be problem?

Comment: It looks like as sessions or cookies involved. Do you use any?

Comment: can you edit your question and add the full code (if it not exceed 50 lines)?

Comment: Yes, session is used. Full code is long. I will try to shorten and will post

Answer (score 2):

first change

```
$Number1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$Number1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

since I believe you are retrieving only 1 row..

you will get ur number as

```
echo $Number1['Number']
```

Dins

Comment: Thanks it works! only instead of echo $Number1['number'] need echo $Number1['Number'].

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo $Number1['Number'] .'<br>';
```