# Mysql Return all values of a table where column is equal to user input

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some sql statements that accepts a number and if that number is equal to the value of a column in a database, it should return all rows in the database that has the same value. Unfortunately the rows only return blog_post_id that has a value 0.

This is my codes below:

```
<?php
$options = array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
$blog_post_id = !empty($_POST['blog_post_id']) ? $_POST['blog_post_id'] 
: '';

$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost","username","password", 
$options);
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE blog_post_id = 
'$blog_post_id'");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
if ($json)
    echo $json;
else
    echo json_last_error_msg();

?>
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  If you used parameters, your query would work.

Comment: Might this SO question help you [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130698/php-pdo-get-only-one-value-from-mysql-value-that-equals-to-variable)

Comment: I recommend using `{}` for conditionals, and indenting params for easier reading of code

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing the point of using the function `prepare()` and you need to check if the query does actually return any results..

```
<?php
$options      = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
);
$blog_post_id = !empty($_POST['blog_post_id']) ? $_POST['blog_post_id'] : '';

$pdo       = new PDO("mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost", "username", "password", $options);
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE blog_post_id = ?");
$statement->execute([$blog_post_id]);
$results   = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = array();

if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $json[] = array(
            'id' => $row['blog_post_id'],
            'Field' => $row['Column'],
            'AnotherField' => $row['AnotherColumn'],
            'AnotherField1' => $row['AnotherColumn1'],
            'ETC' => $row['AnotherColumnName']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
} else {

    echo "no data found";
}

?>
```

Comment: my query returns results when  i set the blog_post_id to the value 1

Comment: what i want is if the user enters 1 or 2 my query should return the results

Comment: do u have id with 2?

Comment: i have an id of 0 and 1

Comment: so how do you expect results if you have id of 0 and 1 with a 2?

Answer (score 0):

You should do variable binding like so:

```
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost","username","password", $options);
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE blog_post_id = :blog_post_id");
$statement->execute(['blog_post_id' => $blog_post_id]);
```

This will also prevent 1st level SQL-Injection as described here: [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)